# how to setup AWS for single page application project with spring boot and react.js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I tried to deploy my single page application with spring boot and react.js. but I don't know where to start. I did my research and EC2 and S3 would be the right setup for deploying spa but I'm not quite sure. is there any resource I could have?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many way to do this.
But I would use AWS CloudFront, and have the EC2 as a source (could also have the EC2 behind application load balancer) and the react.js in an S3 as a source. This way you also get them under a common domain name, and you can easily enforce HTTPS.